# do I have to pass the navController to all my composables?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-compose

I am new to jetpack Composable.
I'm trying to build a new app using Composables in MainActivity.
so there will be only one activity and no fragments and all Composables.
I want to know do I have to pass the navController to all the Composables as parameter so inside the function,I can jump to other composables.
cause I dont find a way to obtain the controller inside my composable function.
hope you can help me. thanks a lot

```
MyApp.kt  without a class
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home_page") {
        composable("home_page") {
            HomePage(HomePageData())
        }
        composable("login_page") {
            LoginPage(navController)
        }

    }
}
```

```
HomePage.kt without a class
@Composable
fun HomePage(viewModel: HomePageData) {
    Surface {
          //val navController = rememberNavController()
          //with this remeberNavController(). I got  another object other than the one in MyApp(). using this controller, some nullPointExpception throwed.
        Text(viewModel.pageText, Modifier.clickable {
           //I want to navigate to LoginPage upon this click.
        })
    }
}
```

here's my code. My problem is that I dont know how to do the jump in the click scope .

Comment: You don't need to pass your ```navController``` to every ```Composable```because it's bad practice. rather you can make a NavHost where you can manage all the navigations.

Comment: can you give me an exapmle for this？                                               `@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home_page") {
        composable("home_page") {
            HomePage(HomePageData(), navController)
        }
        composable("login_page") {
            LoginPage(navController)
        }

    }
}` here's my navHost code. I dont know how to manage my navigations.  and my problem is that I don't know how to call the navController.navigate() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetpack Compose is mostly a `single-activity` application so you can manage navigation between the screens.

Here is the solution. The `NavController` is the central API for the Navigation component. It is stateful and keeps track of the back stack of composables that make up the screens in your app and the state of each screen

For better `Routing` and to avoid any typo errors we are using `Sealed Class`.

**Step 1** : **`Screens.kt`**

```
sealed class Screens(val route : String) {
        object Login : Screens("login")
        object Home : Screens("home")    
}
```

Once You define your routing. now it's time to define the `NavHost` which works as a screen container where you can switch between screens suing `NavController`. Let's see how It works.

**Step 2** : In you `MainActivity` make a composable which will holds `NavHost`.

```
@Composable
fun NestedNavigationExample() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screens.Home.route
    ) {
            composable(route = Screens.Home.route) {
                HomeScreen {
                    navController.navigate(it)
                }
            }
            composable(route = Screens.Login.route) {
                LoginScreen {
                    navController.navigate(it)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Here, we have taken `navController` which will manage screen transitions.
`NavHost` needs a starting or initial screen so we have given `Home` as a starting screen.

**Step 3** : Define your screens

HomeScreen

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit) {
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "Home") },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
        )
    }) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .padding(it)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                navigateTo(Screens.Login.route)
            }) {
                Text(text = "Navigate to Login")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoginScreen

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LoginScreen() {
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "Login") },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
        )
    }) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .padding(it)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
                Text(text = "Login Screen Content")
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: When you want to navigate to a specific route pass it as a lambda parameter and then `navController.navigate(route)` will take you to that screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought I should get the navController object to do the navigation from the beginning, after read your answer and a lot of posts, I give up. thanks again.

Comment: This is an example of navigation best practice. you can follow this for large scale project as well.